# Ruby validation passes in console, fails in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

This is my `EmailContact` model:

```
class EmailContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
end
```

I am using the ruby gem `valid_email`.

I run the following in my rails console, in the same environment as my rake task I will show later:

```
>>   email_contact = EmailContact.new(:email => 'a253545@gmail.com')

>>   email_contact.valid?

     true
```

So, as you can see, in the rails console I am building an `EmailContact` and it is valid.

Then I run this in my rake task:

```
list_entity = {:branch=>"Nashua Branch-YMCA of Greater Nashua", :branch_id=>"485", :call_type=>nil, :client_id=>"2264", :client_name=>"YMCA of Greater Nashua", :date_of_birth=>nil, :email=>"a253545@gmail.com", :first_name=>"Sridhar", :last_name=>"Tipirneni", :list_entity_id=>"277795", :mem_id=>"4085008", :mem_unit_id=>"2138728", :member_id=>"0213262-01", :membership_type=>"Dual 2 Adult Family", :membership_type_id=>"5203", :most_recent_join_date=>nil, :old_membership_type=>nil, :phone_number=>"(970)456-1010", :primary_language=>"English", :termination_date=>nil, :termination_reason=>nil, :unit_id=>"0213262", :unit_type=>nil, :visits=>nil, :"@i:type"=>"c:NpsListEntityDto"}

     email_contact = EmailContact.new(list_entity.except(:"@i:type"))
     puts email_contact.valid?
```

This returns `false`. The only validation, at all, is the `email`. Why does this email validate successfully in my console but fail in my rake task?

FYI, when I remove `:email => true` from my `EmailContact` model and only validate the presence of an `:email`, they both work fine. So the issue is definitely within the `:email => true` piece of my validation, but I don't understand why it passes in one place and fails in another.

## EDIT

In my console, my model looks like this when using the full `list_entity`:

```
#<EmailContact id: nil, branch: "Nashua Branch-YMCA of Greater Nashua", branch_id: 485, call_type: nil, client_id: 2264, client_name: "YMCA of Greater Nashua", date_of_birth: nil, email: "a253545@gmail.com", first_name: "Sridhar", last_name: "Tipirneni", list_entity_id: 277795, mem_id: "4085008", mem_unit_id: "2138728", member_id: "0213262-01", membership_type: "Dual 2 Adult Family", membership_type_id: 5203, most_recent_join_date: nil, old_membership_type: nil, phone_number: "(970)456-1010", primary_language: "English", termination_date: nil, termination_reason: nil, unit_id: "0213262", visits: nil, loaded_at: nil, failed_at: nil, unit_type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, list_id: nil>
```

In my rake task, when I run `email_contact.inspect`, this is returned:

```
#<EmailContact id: nil, branch: "Nashua Branch-YMCA of Greater Nashua", branch_id: 485, call_type: nil, client_id: 2264, client_name: "YMCA of Greater Nashua", date_of_birth: nil, email: "a253545@gmail.com", first_name: "Sridhar", last_name: "Tipirneni", list_entity_id: 277795, mem_id: "4085008", mem_unit_id: "2138728", member_id: "0213262-01", membership_type: "Dual 2 Adult Family", membership_type_id: 5203, most_recent_join_date: nil, old_membership_type: nil, phone_number: "(970)456-1010", primary_language: "English", termination_date: nil, termination_reason: nil, unit_id: "0213262", visits: nil, loaded_at: nil, failed_at: nil, unit_type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, list_id: nil>
```

As you can see, they are both the exact same - The console model is valid, the rake model is invalid.

## EDIT 2

I am using the `valid_email` gem, mentioned above. Here is the filepath:

`/Users/luigi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@hub/gems/valid_email-0.0.4/lib/valid_email/email_validator.rb`

All of my other gems are stored here as well it seems like.

It may also be worth mentioning that I get this warning before the validation fails:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in
the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you
can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
```

Comment: if you user .save! what is the error it returns?

Comment: What happens if, in your console, you do it exactly the same way as in your rake task? The way you're showing it, you're doing it differently.

Comment: It's the exact same result if I do it the same way in my console - I just showed the email piece for simplicity sake. I am using the entire list_entity when building the model in my console though.

Comment: `.save!` returns "Validation failed: Email is invalid"

Comment: Seems like a loading problem. Where (path, filename) did you put your `EmailValidator`?

Comment: @spickermann Edited my post with that info.

Comment: Is the `email_validator` in your `Gemfile`? Do you call `bundle exec rake ...` or just `rake`?

Comment: I have `gem 'valid_email'` in my Gemfile, so the directory is but not necessarily the `email_validator` exact script that is within `lib`. I am calling `bundle exec rake`, and I get the same results with just `rake...`

Comment: please try to remove the gem and see what happens to the rake task

Comment: If I remove the gem, it will work. As I mentioned above, if I simply remove `:email => true` from my validations, which is where the gem is implemented, the validations pass with no issue. That doesn't explain why the gem, in my dev environment, works fine in my rails console but doesn't work in my rake task which is also running in dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 hours later, I found the issue.

Using savon, all of the strings returned in my hash were being converted to a datatype of `Nori::StringWithAttributes`. The encoding was the same (UTF-8), but the class was different.

Running `email_contact.email = email_contact.email.to_s` prior to checking if the model is valid solves the issue.